# pyspark csv write: fields with new line chars in double quotes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing spark dataframe to a csv using following options:

```
     df
     .repartition("col1")
     .write
     .partitionBy("col1")
     .option("header", "true")
     .option("quote", "\"")
     .option("escape", "\"")
     .option("emptyValue", "")
     .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace", False)
     .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace", False)
     .option("maxRecordsPerFile", 100000)
     .csv("some_path")
```

few string columns in my dataframe contains new line characters. I want all fields containing new line to surround with `"`. I couldn't find a way to do this in spark. I know I can use `.option("quoteAll", True)` to have quotes around all fields but I want to avoid doing that.

Here is an e.g. of data

Actual:

```
field1, field2, field3
101, field with new line char at the end
, false
102, field with new line char at the end
, false
```

expected:

```
field1, field2, field3
101, "field with new line char at the end
",another field
102, "field with new line char at the end
",another field
```

EDIT 1: The new line character in data is `\r`(ascii value 13)

Comment: Did you check the output csv, for value containing "\n", the value should be already wrapped with "".

Comment: thanks,output csv isn't wrapped with quotes. One thing I observed after looking a my data it's actually "\r"(ascii code 13). I will update it in original post

Comment: Can you also point me to the documentation where it says columns containing "\n" chars should be wrapped in double quote?

Comment: @error did you find any solution for this, even I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the field that contains the new line character, you can add the quotes around the field value and then write to a csv.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = df.select(field1,concat(F.lit('\"'),field2,F.lit('\"')),field3)
```

Comment: I know the field but this will change the value of fields(by putting `"` in it).